# Virtual machine manager: Error starting domain: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 158: invalid start byte

Tags: python, ubuntu-gnome, network-bridge, utf-8

- Client: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Virtual client: 18.04 LTS
- python 3.8.10

I need to create a bridge on Virtual Machine Manager.

I installed GNOME Boxes and I ran Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. It works fine without bridge checked, but when I open VC in Virtual Machine Manager → *Open*  → *NIC*, set *Bridge mode* and click *Run*, I get this error:

```
Error starting domain: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 158-159: invalid continuation byte

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 111, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 66, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1279, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1234, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 37, in __init__
    err = libvirtmod.virGetLastError()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 158-159: invalid continuation byte
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me.
Running the following command shows the ***default*** network bridge was inactive.

```
sudo virsh net-list --all
```

Used the following command to start ***default*** network bridge.

```
sudo virsh net-start default
```

Used the following command to autostart network bridge.

```
sudo virsh net-autostart --network default
```